# Kotlin - How to iterate through a range when button is clicked?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here I am working on a small app in Android Studio and what I need is for my button "Next" to switch between four images, going one by one. I remember the logic I used for a Dice Roller app which uses a range and the .random function to choose between 1..6. And later, you assign images to those numbers.

That's what I did, and I ran it with the .random function, works flawlessly, now I just need to figure out how to increment through the range one by one when the button is clicked. Going: 1, 2, 3, 4 and then again once it reaches 4.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.artspace

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RectangleShape
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.artspace.ui.theme.ArtSpaceTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ArtSpaceTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    ArtSpace()
                }
            }
        }
    }



    }


@Composable
fun ArtSpace(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var range by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    val imageResource = when(range) {
        1 -> R.drawable.bairen
        2 -> R.drawable.scenic_cliff
        3 -> R.drawable.the_stair_tree
        else -> R.drawable.abandoned




    }

    Column( modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start)
    {
        Row(modifier.padding(10.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(150.dp)
          ) {
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Top)
                    .size(width = 110.dp, height = 50.dp)
            )
            {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.previous))
            }

            Button(
                onClick = { range = (1..4).random() },
                modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Bottom)
                    .size(width = 110.dp, height = 50.dp),
            )
            {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.next))

            }






        }

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(imageResource),
            contentDescription = "cliff",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(600.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .border(3.dp, Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)) {

            Text(
                stringResource(R.string.image_name1),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .border(3.dp, Color.Black, RectangleShape)
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 100.dp)

                )
        }
         }

    }









@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ArtSpacePreview() {
    ArtSpaceTheme {
        ArtSpace()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried going by ``` onClick = { range++} ``` but I'd still need to find a way to reset it after 4

Answer (score 1):

Here we are! I used

```
Button(
                onClick = { range--.until(0)},
                modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Top)
                    .size(width = 110.dp, height = 50.dp)
            )
            {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.previous))
            }

            Button(
                onClick = { range++.until(5) },
                modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Bottom)
                    .size(width = 110.dp, height = 50.dp),
            )
            {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.next))

            }
```